# ember.js: how to delete a record using a view

Tags: event-handling, ember.js

in ember's [official guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/views/), they say it's possible to delete a record using a view, but they don't provide an example of how to do it. i can't understand how views can get the id of the object do destroy.
maybe i didn't understand what's the view purpose? i think it's an event handler (but i see sometimes it's used to render chunks of hbl... maybe that's why i'm confusing)

is there an example of the whole process of deletion anywhere?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, what you want to do is create an `{{action}}` in your view that sends an event to where it should actually be handled: either the controller or the route. (In my case, a little of both)

---

**Note**: Generally, you don't need to write a `View` class for templates, unless the view needs a particular event handler. Ember generates a generic view *on-the-fly*. You can see this through `{{log view}}`:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="app">
    {{log view}}
</script>
```

If you look in the console you will find that the template `app` is associated with a view class:

[image]

---

For example, in the following view template, I'm defining a "Delete" button, which will trigger the action `remove` in the controller.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="product/remove"> 
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Remove</legend>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            Are you sure you want to delete <strong>{{content.name}}</strong>?
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <ht />
    {{#linkTo products class="btn"}}Back to List{{/linkTo}}
    <button {{action remove target="controller"}} class="btn btn-danger">
        Delete
    </button>
</script>
```

The controller simply gets the `content` property and signals the route to fire the `confirmRemove` event, passing its `content` as the argument

```
App.ProductRemoveController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    remove: function() {
        this.get('target').send('confirmRemove', this.get('content'));    
    }
});
```

And the route actually handles it like this:

```
App.ProductRemoveRoute = Em.Route.extend(App.NotifyHandler, {
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        var c = this.controllerFor('product');
        controller.set('content', c.get('content'));
    },
    events: {
        confirmRemove: function(record) {
            record.deleteRecord();

            // should commit here
            // this.get('store').commit();

            this.controllerFor('application').set(
                'notification', 'Product has been removed'
            );
            this.transitionTo('products');
        }
    }
});
```

(see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/FYvuD/))

If you want to handle the event directly in the Route, without talking to the controller, in your view template, you simply omit the `target="controller"`, and the framework will look up for a handler of that event in the controller, and if doesn't find, it will [look up in the route](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/#toc_target-bubbling). In this approach, you *have* to pass the event argument via Handlebars, if any argument is required. In this case, I know that `this` represents the `content` in that template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="product/remove"> 
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Remove</legend>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            Are you sure you want to delete <strong>{{content.name}}</strong>?
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <ht />
    {{#linkTo products class="btn"}}Back to List{{/linkTo}}
    <button {{action confirmRemove this}} class="btn btn-danger">
        Delete
    </button>
</script>
```

With this approach, you don't need to define anything in your controller as it will fire the event directly in the route:

```
App.ProductRemoveController = Em.ObjectController.extend();
```

(see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/XDyFE/))

---

**Update:** In order to have the event handled in the object controller, the `itemController` property has to specify a controller, which should extend `Em.ObjectController`:

```
Depot.TransportDocumentsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
    itemController: 'transportDocument'

Depot.TransportDocumentController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
    removeItem: ->
        alert("aoooo")
```

The only thing that would be changed in a template would be the mention of the `itemController` in the `{{each}}` helper:

```
{{#each doc in controller itemController="transportDocument"}}
    {{doc.number}}
    <!-- rest of the template removed to make this short. -->
    <button {{action removeItem}} class='btn btn-danger btn-small'>
        <i class="icon-white icon-remove"></i>
    </button>
{{/each}}
```

In the action, you don't need to say where the handler is located, as the framework can [find the target](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/#toc_target-bubbling) on its own.

(see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/zSakT/))

Comment: No ember views, just template actions? what did they mean say in the guide, so?

Comment: @AliveDeveloper updated the answer with a note. Basically you don't need a view class unless you want to handle something that doesn't concern the controller or route. Ember generates the necessary code for generic views and controllers.

Comment: last thing, promise: if i call my action inside a cycle {{#each controller}} the interested controller is my ArrayController. But i want it to be my ObjectController. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @AliveDeveloper Read about `itemController` [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html)

Comment: done! it works! thank you. Do u know why there isn't a name convention for this? isn't what i want to do very common? however here was the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sLp8z/1/)

Comment: @AliveDeveloper I've made more edits in the answer about this.